Appium on Google TV: Error executing adbExec. Command output: Error: Intent matches multiple activities; can't stop: Intent
I am running an emulator device of a Google TV with the following capabilities in Node:
config.capabilities = [
    {
        platformName: 'Android',
        'appium:deviceName': 'Television_1080p_API_34',
        'appium:platformVersion': '14.0',
        'appium:orientation': 'LANDSCAPE',
        'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
    },
];

However, I get the following error:
unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.myapp.androidtv' application.
Consider checking the driver's troubleshooting documentation.
Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited with code 1';
Command output: Error: Intent matches multiple activities; can't stop: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 }

There were solutions here and in the Appium forums to include one or both:
'appium:appActivity': '.mainActivity',
'appium:appWaitActivity': '.mainActivity',

but I get the following error instead:
Original error: Activity name '.mainActivity' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
This command won't show anything at all so unsure what the activity should be:
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'
I can run the Android TV emulator fine and can see the app and can manually trigger commands.

The original error is not very helpful but it is due to the missing:
'appium:appActivity': '.mainActivity'
Since I am not getting any values when using adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp', I had to open the .apk file in Android Studio then find the AndroidManifest.xml file and search for <activity> android:name where you can find the activity name used to load the app.
